# Routing within Laravel? .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I'm currently reading through the documentation and completing this quick-start guide:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart#adding-tasks

I'm using Wamp and have installed this Laravel app in "*www/laravel/quickstart5/*"
It works fine to access index through *localhost/laravel/quickstart5/public/*
When I submit a new task I get redirected to *"localhost/task/"*

This is my routes.php

```
<?php


use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Display All Tasks
 */
Route::get('/', function () {
    $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
});
/**
 * Add A New Task
 */
Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $task = new Task;
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/');

    // Create The Task...
});

/**
 * Delete An Existing Task
 */
Route::delete('/task/{id}', function ($id) {
    Task::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

I have a file in /app/ called Task.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    //
}
```

I don't understand how this form is suppose to work.  `"<form action="/task" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">"`

The only thing I get is that I guess I should change the .htaccess in the "/public"-folder

Current .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>



RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: check this http://www.walkswithme.net/laravel-setup-in-linux-machine. setup the Virtual host and edit your host file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/task` will always be relative to the root. You actually have a lot of options to "fix" this - none of which involve editing the .htaccess file.

1. Use the [`url`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-url) helper function. This will generate an absolute URL. In this case, it will be `localhost/laravel/quickstart5/public/task`.

   ```
   action="{{ url('task') }}"
   ```
2. If you named your routes, you can use the [`route`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-route) helper function instead to generate the absolute URL.

   ```
   action="{{ route('task') }}"
   ```
3. Run `php artisan serve` from your favorite CLI. Then, you can access your Laravel project from `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: The `redirect('/')` is the actual root of the issue, not the form actions.

Comment: @Cryode What makes you say that? His form is never submitted because by prepending his URL with a slash, his action URL is now relative to the root of the web server aka `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks, the `url` helper function solved it straight away!

Comment: I have another form which submits this:
`<form action="{{ url('/task/') }}{{ $task->id }}" method="POST">`

Although for some reason I get redirected to a page _localhost/laravel/quickstart5/public/task5_

Without the last "/" after _/task_
I solved it by removing the "/" in the route method call.

So I got it to work, but I thought this problem was odd.

Comment: @user2479698 Try this instead: `{{ url('/task/' . $task->id) }}`

Comment: @ThomasKim My mistake, I did not see the original form action code in the original post, so I assumed that the request was working fine and the redirected page afterwards was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add to your vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/laravel/quickstart5/public"
    ServerName quickstart5.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add this line to your hosts file and restart apache

```
127.0.0.1 quickstart5.local
```

Now you can access your project through: http://quickstart5.local

For a more detailed guide on doing the above see here: https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp